# Why does my main nav show up on two lines instead of one on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Site: http://www.zrrdigitalmedia.com

My main nav menu shows up on two lines instead of one on mobile devices. I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap 2.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="navRow">
            <div class="span12 text-center">
                <nav class="container-fluid" name="nav">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
                        <li>
                            <a name="sites" href="#">SITES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a name="logos" href="#">LOGOS</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a name="ads" href="#">ADS</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a name="prints" href="#">PRINTS</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a name="about" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="mailto:zrubinrattet@gmail.com">CONTACT</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    h1{
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
    .headerText{
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    #headerBG{
        padding: 0px;
    }
    #navRow{
        top: 50px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    #topFiller{
        height: 100px;
    }
    .nav-pills > li > a,
    .nav-pills > li > a:focus {
        font-size: 30px;
        padding: 5%;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
    h1{
        font-size: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 15px;
    }
    .thumbnail p {
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 12px;
    }
    .headerText{
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    #headerBG{
        padding: 0px;
        height:40px;
    }
    #navRow{
        top: 40px;
        height: 25px;
    }
    #topFiller{
        height: 70px;
    }
    .nav{
        margin: 0;
    }
    .nav-pills > li > a,
    .nav-pills > li > a:focus {
        font-size: 17px;
        padding: 5%;
    }
}
```

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeStuff();
    $(window).on('resize',resizeStuff);

    function resizeStuff(){
        if($(window).width()<=600 && $(window).width()>0){
            $('#leftFiller').removeClass('span3');
            $('#leftFiller').addClass('span1');
            $('#rightFiller').removeClass('span3');
            $('#leftFiller').addClass('span1');
            $('#content').removeClass('span6');
            $('#content').addClass('span10');
        }
        else{
            $('#leftFiller').removeClass('span1');
            $('#leftFiller').addClass('span2');
            $('#rightFiller').removeClass('span1');
            $('#leftFiller').addClass('span2');
            $('#content').removeClass('span10');
            $('#content').addClass('span8');
        }
});
```

I need to make sure the main nav shows up on one line instead of two. When I rotate my phone from landscape to portrait to landscape, or portrait to landscape to portrait, the main nav resizes as it should. But I need this to happen when the site loads. I'm at a loss of ideas as to why this is happening. Can anyone provide assistance please? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything when resizing in the browser. It's all one line

Comment: Same here. It only happens on mobile devices. I've only been able to test this on Android devices, but if anyone has an iPhone please let me know if this problem arises.

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://m.imgur.com/xlcdicx

Comment: Thanks Shrink. That's a good sign that it's working on iPhone. Now if I could only figure out why it's misbehaving on Android. It looks like the CSS media queries aren't taking effect until after the JS has run. Could this be possible/what's causing the misbehavior?

Comment: Well that was Android. And I've also tested it on iPhone and it works fine. I'm not sure if it's a device related issue but it works fine on the Nexus 5 and iPhone 5S.

Comment: Also take a look at Chrome Canary. You can emulate a bunch of different devices on it to test your website. https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html

Answer (score 0):

The navigation only splits up when the screen is narrower than 239 pixels. The resizer does not shrink the text fast enough for the navigation to stay on one line.